# How do you get the information for one person

Tags: google-people-api

How do you use people.get to get the information for someone with a particular first and surname? I am confused as to how it works as there doesn't seem to be a people.search that you can call first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot filter by fields (or at all). You can, however, get a list of contacts with people.conections.list and find you contact in the response.